# Firebase hitcounter: hits display but won't increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a hit counter that displays in the console of my page.  Here is the relevant code:

```
    var database = firebase.database();



   database.ref().on("value", function(snapshot) {

      console.log("Logging snapshot.val " + snapshot.val());

      console.log("Logging hits " + snapshot.val().hits);

      var hitCounter = snapshot.val().hits;

      console.log("hitCounter is " + hitCounter)
    }, function(errorObject) {

      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });

//so I can get it to display the value in the database, but not to increase.  WTF
  function showStuff() {
    $("#content").fadeIn("slow");

      hitCounter++;
      console.log("hitCounter in showstuff() function is = " + hitCounter);
      //this console log above doesn't even fire.  WTF!?
      //Ask on stack overflow some other time

      database.ref().set({
        hits: hitCounter
      });


}
```

As the comments indicate, I can get the number in the database to display, but not to increase.  Even the console.log in showStuff() does not fire (yet the fade in does).  What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

you are using a event callback that will be passed a snapshot every time the data is changed. If you need to show that value using your `showStuff` function, you have to call it in your callback function

```
 database.ref().on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Logging snapshot.val " + snapshot.val());
  console.log("Logging hits " + snapshot.val().hits);

  var hitCounter = snapshot.val().hits;
  console.log("hitCounter is " + hitCounter);


  showStuff();

}, function(errorObject) {

  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: Okay, but the "showStuff()" function also contains visual effects.  Will these be triggered every time there is a new hit, even if it from a different person?  It seems like that would happen.

Comment: I tried something similar, splitting "showStuff()" into two functions called showStuff() and addHits(), then subbed in showStuff() for addHits() in your code, but it didn't seem to change anything.